# Vagrant, VirtualBox, Supervisord: When is synced folder mounted?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, puppet, supervisord

I'm running a virtual machine with Supervisord to start and maintain several important background processes. I create the virtual machine with vagrant and virtualbox, and provision it with puppet. When the machine starts up supervisord grabs all the .conf files in /etc/supervisor/conf.d and tries to run them. Unfortunately, when I run

```
Vagrant up
```

supervisord starts trying to run the files in conf.d immediately, before the synced folders are shared. So starting some background processes like Xvfb runs just fine, but starting my stat tracker, which resides within the synced folder, wont be possible. In fact, I see in the supervisord logs multiple attempts to start the process, complaining that it can't find the file, and finally giving up. Then, once the machine is fully running I can SSH in and run the exact same command in the .conf file and start the process myself.

I have created an intermediary script to loop continuously, waiting for the synced folder to become available, and then starting the processes I want. But in this case, supervisor does not have a way to make sure the process remains running, and it feels like a hack.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Maybe from within puppet or vagrant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more googling I found this which solved my problem: http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/

Comment: New link for this article is https://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount.html